# Scala not a member of Any

Tags: scala

```
def interpolate(l:List[Tuple2[String,String]]) : List[Tuple2[java.util.Date, Long]] = {
   val mapped : List[Tuple2[java.util.Date, Long]] = l.map(item => (format.parse(item._1), item._2.toLong ) )
   val results = ListBuffer[Tuple2[java.util.Date, Long]]()
   val last : Option[Tuple2[java.util.Date, Long]] = None
   mapped.foreach( item => 
      if(!last.isEmpty) {

         val daysItem = item._1.getTime() / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24
         val daysLast = last.get._1.getTime() / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24
         if( daysItem - daysLast > 1 ) {
           val slope = (item._2 - last.get._2) / (daysItem - daysLast)
           val days = daysLast until daysItem
           val missingChunk : List[Tuple2[java.util.Date, Long]] = days.map( day => (new Date(day * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000), slope * day)).toList
           results ++= missingChunk
         }

      }

      //results += item
      last = Some(item)
   )

   results.toList
}
```

Error:

```
<console>:45: error: value last is not a member of Any
possible cause: maybe a semicolon is missing before `value last'?
             last = Some(item)
             ^
```

Comment: `last` is a `val`.  You can't reassign its value.

Comment: You might want to look at nscala-time to simplify some of the date operations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 problems here:

1) multiple statements needs `{...}` brackets:

from

```
mapped.foreach((item: (Date, Long)) => item
  XXX // OK
  YYY // NO
)
```

to

```
mapped.foreach { (item: (Date, Long)) => item
  XXX // OK
  YYY // OK
}
```

2) `val` can't be reassigned:

from

```
val last: Option[Tuple2[java.util.Date, Long]] = None
```

to

```
var last: Option[Tuple2[java.util.Date, Long]] = None
```

---

**Refactor #1**

I would try to avoid using `var`. It seems that with this condition `if (last.isDefined)` probably we are trying to `zip` the list with itself:

```
scala> val l = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
scala> l.zip(l.tail)
List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (4,5))
```

Refactoring your example:

```
  import java.util.Date

  def interpolate(l: List[(String, String)]): List[(Date, Long)] = {
    val mapped: List[(Date, Long)] = l.map(item => (format.parse(item._1), item._2.toLong))
    val results = ListBuffer[(Date, Long)]()

    mapped.zip(mapped.tail).foreach { case ((lastDate, lastLong), (itemDate, itemLong)) =>
      val daysItem = itemDate.getTime / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24
      val daysLast = lastDate.getTime / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24
      if (daysItem - daysLast > 1) {
        val slope = (itemLong - lastLong) / (daysItem - daysLast)
        val days = daysLast until daysItem
        val missingChunk: List[(Date, Long)] = days.map(day => (new Date(day * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000), slope * day)).toList
        results ++= missingChunk
      }
    }

    results.toList
  }
```

---

**Refactor #2**

`ListBuffer` is a mutable collection. In our scenario it seems we are trying to `flatten` the `missingChunk`s.

Keep refactoring:

```
  def interpolate(l: List[(String, String)]): List[(Date, Long)] = {
    val mapped: List[(Date, Long)] = l.map(item => (format.parse(item._1), item._2.toLong))
    val missingChunks = mapped.zip(mapped.tail).map { case ((lastDate, lastLong), (itemDate, itemLong)) =>
      val daysItem = itemDate.getTime / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24
      val daysLast = lastDate.getTime / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24
      if (daysItem - daysLast > 1) {
        val slope = (itemLong - lastLong) / (daysItem - daysLast)
        val days = daysLast until daysItem
        days.map(day => (new Date(day * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000), slope * day)).toList
      } else List.empty[(Date, Long)]
    }

    missingChunks.flatten
  }
```

Comment: Instead of zipping with its own tail you can use [`sliding`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.IterableLike@sliding(size:Int,step:Int):Iterator[Repr])